# Is $(\Bbb{Q},+)$ isomorphic to $(\Bbb{Q}_{>0},\cdot)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to know if $(\Bbb{Q},+)\cong (\Bbb{Q}_{>0},\cdot)$, but have no idea where to begin my proof. Can anyone offer a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: In $({\mathbb Q},+)$ you can divide any element by $2$, but some elements of $({\mathbb Q}_{>0},.)$ do not have square roots.

Comment: Ah! Of course. Perfectly crafted hint! Thank you.

Comment: The first things to check for these problems are torsion, divisibility and rank.

Comment: Oh. I haven't studied torsion